# Regular Expressions to Search for Hex color codes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

So I'm trying to minify some code and I'm using the PHP function [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to do so. I'm trying to compress Hex colors. For example:

```
#FF0000 => #F00
```

I [found some code](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/35751-shortening-six-digit-hex-color-code/) over the interwebs and so far, this is what I have:

```
$hex_char = '[a-f0-9]';
$html = preg_replace("/(?<=^#)($hex_char)\\1($hex_char)\\2($hex_char)\\3\z/i", '\1\2\3', $html);
```

It works for a string like:

```
$html = "#FF0000";
```

**OK, so the real problem** is that I need the code to search for all the Hex colors in a chunk of code like CSS, etc. It would be something like this:

```
<?php

$html = '
.this{
    color: #FF0000;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
';

$hex_char = '[a-f0-9]';
$html = preg_replace("/(?<=^#)($hex_char)\\1($hex_char)\\2($hex_char)\\3\z/i", '\1\2\3', $html);
echo $html;

?>
```

How can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: use `g` for `global`: `$html = preg_replace("/(?<=^#)($hex_char)\\1($hex_char)\\2($hex_char)\\3\z/ig", '\1\2\3', $html);`

Comment: B aware that this is a destructive replace, ie, you lose information in reducing the hex code representation from 6 to 3 chars. Do you actually mean to replace *only* those that can be reduced non-destructively? ie, those that match XXYYZZ patterns, but *not* those that don't match that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the lookbehind and end of the string anchor from your regex.

```
<?php
$html = <<<EOT
.this{
    color: #FF0000;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
EOT;
$hex_char = '[a-f0-9A-F]';
$html = preg_replace("~#($hex_char)\\1($hex_char)\\2($hex_char)\\3~", '#$1$2$3', $html);
echo $html;
?>
```

**Output:**

```
.this{
    color: #F00;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `^` and `\z` anchors.

```
'/\#\K([a-f0-9])\1([a-f0-9])\2([a-f0-9])\3/i'
```

Or

```
 #  '/(?<=\#)([a-f0-9])\1([a-f0-9])\2([a-f0-9])\3/i'

 (?xi-)
 (?<= \# )
 ( [a-f0-9] )
 \1 
 ( [a-f0-9] )
 \2 
 ( [a-f0-9] )
 \3
```